# Maximum run-time speed with Intel compiler on VS 10 (C++)

Tags: c++, performance, optimization, intel

I am trying to optimize my code to make run as fast as possible at run-time. I compared VS with Intel by switching several optimization options but I have not noticed a remarkable difference. However, since my processor is Intel it should be faster. What optimization switches do you suggest to maximize speed?

Comment: The best options are application-dependent, and you've told us nothing about your code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The compilers have a slightly different focus.

Microsoft traditionally targets code bases like the Windows OS and SQL Server (surprise). That code contains lots of integer type code and not a lot of heavy loops. Their compiler produces good code for that kind of apps.

Intel focuses more of computation intensive apps with more floating point computations and code that might benefit from aggressive loop unrolling.

Like you, I have noticed that my code that is well tuned for the MS compiler doesn't benefit from being recompiled with the Intel compiler.

Comment: My code is of second type in which there are a lot of floating point operations and loops. I set loop unrolling to 0 and then 100 but there is no difference.

Answer (score 2):

> However, since my processor is Intel it should be faster

No - Intel's CPU specs, microcode and programming manuals are available to any compiler writers. Intel have no particular advantage

Optimisation can only do so much to overcome poorly designed code. Both compilers are probably doing pretty much the same optimisation.

edit:
It's 10years since I worked in HPC but back then Intel and PCG compilers beat everything else hands down, GCC was pretty good and MSVC was terrible. Since then Intel is no longer the default compiler for your final product build, GCC generally has cutting edge whole program optmisation techniques implemented first but MSFT's compiler has advanced out of all recognition. One reason is that MSFT now uses their own compiler for  internal builds.

Answer (score 0):

It would be difficult to provide a one-size-fits-all answer to that question.  If, though, you can do a reasonable job of testing real world scenarios, then using [profile guided optimization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e7k32f4k.aspx) could help.  It can provide feedback for specific test runs.